# Change default parameters

Tags: customization

I want to change the default parameter from '0.010' to '0.0001' of the select similar by area box. The parameter can be found here:
*Edit* > *Face Select* > *Select Similar* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) > *Area*

[image]

Comment: Currently, there isn't a way to set the default parameters permanently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The values are stored in the *Startup-File* if you change them after launching Blender you can set the values and save the default-scene as *Startup File* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>.

You can also restore the [*Factory Settings*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences) from the Menu: *File / Load Factory Settings*.